# Orbeon forms dynamic data dropdown language URL parameter

Tags: orbeon

I am trying to create an Orbeon Forms dynamic dropdown.

At this moment it is working fine but now I need to make it multi language. The service invoked by the dropdown accepts one parameter to return data translated to the proper language.

I am trying to configure URL like the following:

```
http://myhost/myservice?language={$lang}
```

but when I test the drop-down and I change the language it is not working.

Is there any way to make dynamic drop-down localizable?

Orbeon version is Orbeon Forms 2017.1.1.201709122316 PE

Comment: At this moment I am using [this](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/advanced/services-and-actions/actions#internationalization) as workaround **but I am still interested in knowing if it is possible to do it with a dynamic URL**. _Note_ I had to use `fr:lang()` instead of `$fr-lang`

Comment: You're saying that you used `http://myhost/myservice?language={fr:lang()}`, right? If so, using `fr:lang()` doesn't look like a workaround to me, but the right way to do it. Alternatively, your service could return the labels in all the languages you need to support, and in the "Label XPath expression" you could use `fr:lang()` to pick the label in the right language.

Comment: Hi @avernet, after trying the workaround that i mention in my previous comment and that is what you recommend as second option, i have tried to tests my service wiht `http://myhost/myservice?language={fr:lang()}` and now it its working! The problem to me was find the correct way to access current language. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent, I'll then just post an answer with that URL, and thank you for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`fr:lang()` function](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/extension-functions/extension-form-runner#fr-lang) returns the current language, so you can setup the Dynamic Data Dropdown with a URL as follows:

```
http://myhost/myservice?language={fr:lang()}
```